# Call handler initially in python

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a datatable which may contain some data at the time of start of application.

My datatable is showing data when one request has been sent to the server, because initially view.py is not being called.

How can I ensure that views.py is called at application start so that my template can pick up the values.

I am working with django.

Comment: Ok Daniel i am very sorry. Now tell me how to do that?

Comment: There is an accept-Button next to each answer right where you can up- and down vote them

Comment: When you have done that could you please re-read your question and make it a little more intelligible - I am having a lot of trouble working our what you're trying to ask.

Comment: Ok, jus tell me how to call handler in django when application startup so that i will be able to send some values on client side initially.

Answer (score 0):

If you are finding that views.py is not used, you may have done something funky with your app. I would suggest that you read [the manual](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/) before trying to write an application in django, rather than posting garbled messages on a Q&A website. Until you know more or less what you're doing, you're not going to know how to ask for help.

Answer (score 0):

If by 'starting'' an application you mean opening the browser on the initial page (it's a web application after all) you may consider to put in the urls.py configuration file the root path:

```
    (r'^$' , 'path.to.main.view.mainpage'),
```